# Dash and Panel don't load

Tags: 14.04, unity-dash, panel

The top panel and Unity Dash dont apear.

Aslo Window Decoration donw apear (neither on top nor on left/right or bot) some windows are full screen all the time due to this, others in normal size (cant full screen)

Comment: Maybe `compiz` crashes because of your hardware isn't supported. Please make sure if your hardware supports 3D acceleration. Then `ubuntu-drivers` from the command-line (Ctrl+Alt+T) may help you find a working driver.

Comment: Maybe compiz crashes because of your hardware isn't supported.

it is supported, it said so on another command i execute (i can't remember what command was)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resetting Compiz, as there may be some problem with it. Many time while trying diffrent desktop environment it also occurs. 
To reset all the Compiz settings (this includes all the plugins settings, etc.) to the default values, open a terminal (don't run it with ALT + F2! Generally while everything is fine the top panel and launcher gets disappear after running the first command but will show up after the second one so use a terminal) and type:

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compizconfig-1
unity --reset
```

You can also try:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig
```

Comment: error reset is now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

error reset is now deprecated

this seems to be the new command
"unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity"

but dont this mesage is the last:

g_settings_set_value: value for key 'visual-bell-type' in schema 'org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences' is outside of valid range

(something like this)

so... i pressed Control+C to abort then the terminal crashed  (the scroll bar work and nautilus) but the problem was unsolved yet...

then i force shutdown (finger at the physical turnoff button)

and for my surprise, when i boot up again, it was working fine.

thanks, i tried so many things and somewow this works =)